# Unable to connect to endpoint when writing to S3 using Tensorflow

Tags: amazon-s3, tensorflow

Tensorflow 1.4.0 comes with the S3 filesystem driver by default. I'm having trouble using it, and have this minimal example, that does not work for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.gfile.Open("s3://bucket/plipp", mode='w')
f.write("foo")
f.close()
```

which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.close()
  File "/Users/me/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 234, in close
    pywrap_tensorflow.Set_TF_Status_from_Status(status, ret_status)
  File "/Users/me/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: : Unable to connect to endpoint
```

From what I can see, it seems like "Unable to connect to endpoint" is an error from the C++ AWS SDK. I've given myself `*` permissions to the bucket.

My bucket is in `eu-west-1` and I've tried doing `export S3_ENDPOINT=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` and `export S3_REGION=eu-west-1` since it seems that those variables are consumed by the [S3 driver](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b3d5ec90bc6b7ae7822ea82d82b41e529c5e047a/tensorflow/core/platform/s3/s3_file_system.cc), but this changes nothing.

I've also tried using `s3://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/plipp` as the path, instead of just using the bucket name.

I can copy files to the bucket fine:

```
~> aws s3 cp foo s3://bucket/plipp 
upload: ./foo to s3://bucket/plipp
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? How can I debug further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what went wrong last time I tried this, but now I got it working by just doing `export S3_REGION=eu-west-1` and writing to the bucket with

```
with tf.gfile.Open("s3://bucket/plipp", mode='w') as f:
    f.write("foo")
```

So, don't export the `S3_ENDPOINT` variable.